# Entity framework 7 (core) RC2 many-to-many relationship with itself and query

Tags: entity-framework, linq, many-to-many

Is it possible to create an entity `Socket` with ***many-to-many*** relationship for itself?

The typical PostTag example I am familiar from the EF Core documentation. However, I'm not quite sure how to create this kind of relationship with only one entity and one intermediate table `SocketSocket`.

**Here's example:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SocketSocket>()
    .HasKey(ss => new { ss.SocketToId, ss.SocketFromId});
modelBuilder.Entity<SocketSocket>()
    .HasOne(ss => ss.SocketTo)
    .WithMany(s => s.ConnectedToSockets)
    .HasForeignKey(ss => ss.SocketToId);
modelBuilder.Entity<SocketSocket>()
    .HasOne(ss => ss.SocketFrom)
    .WithMany(s => s.ConnectedToSockets)
    .HasForeignKey(ss => ss.SocketFromId);
```

How can I then use this model properly; add connections and query?

**Adding relationship ?**

```
var joinTable = new SocketSocket
{
    SocketToId = socketTo.SocketId,
    SocketTo = socketTo,
    SocketFromId = socketFrom.SocketId,
    SocketFrom = socketFrom
};
DatabaseContext.SocketSockets.Add(joinTable);
```

**Query ?**

How to efficiently find all the sockets which are connected into one socket?