# Entity framework Core 1.1 How to create many-to-many relationship to itself

Tags: c#, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

### The problem

I am wondering what is the correct way to create self referencing entity. This entity can have relationship to as many copies of itself as is mapped.

I have already created the following implementation, however I am not sure what is the correct approach **(?)**

After updating into EF 1.1 I have not been able to delete the SocketSocket stored data by using simple `Context.SocketSockets.Remove(entity);`
**EDIT1:** *removing seems to be working properly.*

I am using SQLite as database.

[image: The desired result]

### Fluent api

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<SocketSocket>()
        .HasKey(ss => new { ss.SocketToId, ss.SocketFromId});
    modelBuilder.Entity<SocketSocket>()
        .HasOne(ss => ss.SocketTo)
        .WithMany()
        .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    modelBuilder.Entity<SocketSocket>()
        .HasOne(ss => ss.SocketFrom)
        .WithMany(s => s.ConnectedToSockets)
        .HasForeignKey(ss => ss.SocketFromId)
        .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

### Intermediate table

```
public class SocketSocket : ModelBase
{
    // many-to-one relaton for cableType
    private string _cableType;
    [DataMember]
    public string CableType
    {
        get
        {
            return _cableType;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_cableType == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _cableType = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CableType", (valid) => { AppMessages.EntityIsValid.Send(valid); });
        }
    }

    public virtual CableType CableType1 { get; set; }

    // intermediate table between Socket1 and SocketSocket
    public int SocketToId { get; set; }
    public Socket SocketTo { get; set; }

    // intermediate table between Socket2 and Socketsocket
    public int SocketFromId { get; set; }
    public Socket SocketFrom { get; set; }
}
```

### Result

```
CREATE TABLE SocketSockets (
    SocketToId            INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SocketFromId          INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CableType             TEXT,
    CableType1CableTypeId INTEGER,
    HasErrors             INTEGER NOT NULL,
    IsValid               INTEGER NOT NULL,
    SocketSocketId        INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_SocketSockets PRIMARY KEY (
        SocketToId,
        SocketFromId
    ),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SocketSockets_CableTypes_CableType1CableTypeId FOREIGN KEY (
        CableType1CableTypeId
    )
    REFERENCES CableTypes (CableTypeId) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT FK_SocketSockets_Sockets_SocketFromId FOREIGN KEY (
        SocketFromId
    )
    REFERENCES Sockets (SocketId) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT FK_SocketSockets_Sockets_SocketToId FOREIGN KEY (
        SocketToId
    )
    REFERENCES Sockets (SocketId) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

My earlier topic realted question: [Entity framework 7 (core) RC2 many-to-many relationship with itself and query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808131/entity-framework-7-core-rc2-many-to-many-relationship-with-itself-and-query)

Comment: You code looks good except field `SocketSocketId`... Are you sure you have NO this field in your `SocketSocket` classs and/or in `ModelBase`? And what exception you receive when calling `Context.SocketSockets.Remove(entity)`?

Comment: You are right, SocketSocketId remained in my class, and it seem to be unnecessary. Additionally seems that removing data is now working, my mistake of implementation. No exceptions. And do you think this is proper way to implement this type of relation where sockets can have relationships to itself?

Comment: Because this `ConnectedSockets` in class `Socket` seems to be quite useless with my approach ?

Comment: If you need many-to-many relation between different `Socket` - you need additional table, like `ConnectedSocket` in your example - it's OK. May be you may play with EF (may be it can generate many-to-many table itself, without explicit class), but I never tried this, because with this approach you lose ability to directly query/manipulate data this table.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comments! As far as I have understood EF Core 1.1 does not yet support automatically many-to-many relationships: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships